# Create-React-App failing to load in Localhost with continous spinner

Tags: reactjs, debugging, loading

Recently I've been having a frustrating issue that I can't seem to resolve. When trying to open a project created with Create-react-app the project compiles successfully, however when trying to access localhost:3001 the page is shown continously loading.

I haven't added any new code to my CRA template, so I don't think it could be a code-related issue. And orginally this issue only appeared with the new CRA projects I created, however as of today even my older projects wont load.

Compile Message

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view themify in the browser.

  Local:            http://localhost:3001        
  On Your Network:  http://10.0.0.36:3001        

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use yarn build.
```

Some of the steps I've already tried include :

- Clearing Chrome cache
- Creating a new CRA project ( same loading issue )
- Opening on a new port ( same loading issue as well )
- Opening in a new browser ( same issue )

Comment: In your compile message it says that you can acess it on http://localhost:3001, but you write that you try to access it on http://localhost:3000, is this a typo or do you try to acess the wrong page?

Comment: Oops sorry , thats a typo! I was originally trying to open in on localhost:3000, and then I decided to try opening in on different ports.

Comment: Hmmm, could you please provide your folder structure as well as App.js code? Also, have you tried accessing the IP under localhost?

Comment: Ps: localhost should be 127.0.0.0:3000 by default, that's why I want you to try the IP under localhost.

Comment: I tried using the IP under it as well, but it still wouldnt load.

Comment: Update: I tried again using the IP address and it worked for a newly created react project, but not for one that already had  extra code added to it.